# Elo rating system with multiple skills

Tags: algorithm, rating, scoring

Does anybody have a good idea as to how I could score multiple skills, and then combine them as a 'top level'-Elo rating?

Use case:
I want to rate a student. I give the student 100 English exercises, these exercises are of different types - i.e. 25 grammar exercises, 25 vocabulary exercises, 25 listening exercises, and 25 apprehension exercises.

Then I would like to be able to calculate four individual Elo-ratings, as well as one combined rating that shows how well the student generally is at English.

Comment: Use a weighted average of each score? This seems very opinion-based.

Comment: Indeed it does. I am also looking into if there would be other better ways to calculate a rating on the student.

Comment: Can we assume that these questions are going to lots of students at once?  Do all students get the same questions, or do they vary (as happens with, eg, the SAT)? And are you wedded to Elo, or is any scheme that seems reasonable going to work for you?

Comment: Keep in mind that Elo (and other similar) rating system doesn't estimate an absolute strength. It only estimates it relatively to the pool of the direct competitors.

Comment: @btilly The students get different variations of the same questions. The idea is that, the system will act as a practice system for extra homework. That is one of the reasons a scoring system is needed, so that we can deliver exercises to the right level. I am in no way married to Elo, any algorithm that is proven would work for me.

Comment: @user58697 Indeed, and that is also one of the strengths of Elo. When the exercises get an Elo score as well, it will act as one big ecosystem where the exercises find their rightful place(Elo rating) and the students over time will have a better chance at improving their knowledge.

Comment: Then just run match-ups. A student rated `Rs`, in a match against an exercise rated `Re` is expected to score `x(Rx- Re)` points. After the exam, adjust the ratings according to the difference of actual score, and the expected score. Of course you have to figure out how to assign initial ratings, but it seems secondary.